# bluetooth chat in android emulator

Tags: android, bluetooth

i downloaded the free sample of bluetooth chat for android mobiles.

i tried to run it on the emulator having SDK platform android 3.2 and API 13 but on the emulator the bluetooth device is deactivated.

How can I activate it and run the bluetooth chat app. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the emulator does not support Bluetooth so you need a real device for this